# Why is this error "local variable cannot be declared in this scope because it ... is already used"?

Tags: c#, recursion, delegates, lambda, closures

I am trying to run the code from the blog article by [Eric Lippert "Why does a recursive lambda cause a definite assignment error?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/08/18/why-does-a-recursive-lambda-cause-a-definite-assignment-error.aspx)

but instead of running (or giving the compilation "definite assignment error" I am getting:

> A local variable named 't' cannot be declared in this scope because it
>   would give a different meaning to 't', which is already used in a
>   'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Why?
Where is it already used in parent or current scope?
Tried to rename it having gotten the same error
How should I change the code to launch this code?

```
using System;
namespace LippertRecursiveLambdaError
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Tree<int> tree = new Tree<int>
      (3, new Tree<int>
             (4, new Tree<int>(1), null), 
          new Tree<int>(5));
      PrintTree(tree);
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    delegate void Action<A>(A a);
    delegate void Traversal<T>(Tree<T> t, Action<T> a);

  static void DepthFirstTraversal<T>(Tree<T> t, Action<T> a)
  {
    if (t == null) return;
    a(t.Value);
    DepthFirstTraversal(t.Left, a);
    DepthFirstTraversal(t.Right, a);
  }
  static void Traverse<T>(Tree<T> t, Traversal<T> f, Action<T> a)
  {
    f(t, a);
  }
  static void Print<T>(T t)
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
  }
  /*static void PrintTree<T>(Tree<T> t)
  {
    Traverse(t, DepthFirstTraversal, Print);
  }*/

  static void PrintTree<T>(Tree<T> t)
  {
    //Traversal<T> df = (t, a)=>          **************
    Traversal<T> df = null;
    //========================================
//The next line gives compilation error
//A local variable named 't' cannot be declared in this scope 
//because it would give a different meaning to 't', 
//which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else       
    df = (t,
      a) =>
     {
       if (t == null) return;
       a(t.Value);
       df(t.Left, a);
       df(t.Right, a);
     };
  Traverse(t, df, Print);
  }//PrintTree
  }//class
  class Tree<T>
  {
    public Tree<T> Left;
    public Tree<T> Right;
    public T Value;

    public Tree(T value) 
    { 
       Value = value; 
    }
    public Tree(T value, Tree<T> left, Tree<T> right) 
    { 
        Value = value; 
        Left = left; 
        Right = right; 
    }
  } 
}//namespace
```

Comment: Whoops, you are absolutely right, that is a typo. My bad. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Eric_Lippert, thanks, wanted to find you in StackOverflow to inform abt this question but it was answered superfast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  static void PrintTree<T>(Tree<T> t)
  {
    //Traversal<T> df = (t, a)=>          **************
    Traversal<T> df = null;
    //========================================

    df = (t,      a) =>
     {
       if (t == null) return;
       a(t.Value);
       df(t.Left, a);
       df(t.Right, a);
     };
    }
```

That's because `Tree<T> t` is one declaration 
And `(t,a) =>`  is another declaration.. practically the same thing as saying:

```
int someFunction(T t, U a)
//Assuming int is the return type
```

Anyway to fix: change `t` to another identifier.. `n` for example

```
df = (n,a) =>{
           if (n == null) return;
           a(n.Value);
           df(n.Left, a);
           df(n.Right, a);
         };
        }
```

Comment: +1: Nice answer, but I would chosen `n` (for node) instead of `u`.

Comment: Ooops. I tried to rename before in vain. Probably have chosen the wrong letters (identifier). Mystery... I am just curious how ppl write such (knock-outing me) code without running it?

Comment: Yes, this worked. I accepted the answer.... I mean - before posting I tried to rename from `t` to `t1` but  it did not work... I am curious how the code in article was written if it did not correspond to what was written (in text editor)?!

Comment: The honest answer would be.. I have no idea :(